# IntelliJ mac JRE home

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I have a shared workspace between my Windows-based laptop and Macbook, today when I wanted to work with my Mac on the project that I got used to work on Windows, I faced this error in the compilation:

> 12:02:30 Compilation completed successfully in 21s 530ms
>   12:02:30 Error running GUI: 'C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101' is not a valid JRE home

Would you please let me know what should I do to resolve this problem? Please note that I checked for the SDK address in my project and it is correctly adjusted to the Mac JDK, but I could not find the 'C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101' anywhere in my project structure!

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

It is right there in the edit configurations.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you installed your JRE, it's searching for `C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101` which is on your PC.

I don't use a Mac, but find your installation folder, and put it into IntelliJ Idea. :)